# Alfresco access right to single document

Tags: alfresco, rules

I'm trying to realize a shared document system with Alfresco Community CMS 4.2d.

In my scenario I have some groups of users. For example User1 and User2 belong to GroupA and User3 and User4 belongs to GroupB.
For each group I create a folder with exclusive access to a specific group.

GroupA -> FolderA

GroupB -> Folder B

I want to give the opportunity to a user (ex. User1) to set the access right to a external user group (ex. User3) to see a specific document.

Comment: Looks fairly standard. Ought to work out of the box. What have you tried, and where did it fall down?

Comment: I created a global site. Into this site for each group (loggin-in with admin account) I create a folder from a custom template. Then I manage permissions giving access rights to specified group... I'm newbie of Alfresco, so if there is a tutorial or a guide that explain an easier method to do this, I'll appreciate. thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the user who have been added with Collaborator role on particular folder would be able to give role to new user(User3). So, in your case if you add User1 as collaborator of FolderA he should be able to manage that external user(User3) as he will be able to see that manage space user action from where any user be added or removed from space.